# Update the result for every record

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

I have an excel sheet in which there are two columns number1 and number2.For every iteration I need to take the number 1 and number 2 from cells and add it and I need to update the addition result in the third column say "Result".I am trying to achieve this using OLE DB method,but the same result is updating in all the cells.Please find the code below.

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Sub TestMacro()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:D20").ClearContents
DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes;Option=3;"
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
select_query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
cn.Open sconnect
With rs
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .Source = select_query
    .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .CursorLocation = adUseServer
    .Open
End With
Do While Not rs.EOF


  num1 = rs.Fields(0).Value
  num2 = rs.Fields(1).Value
  rs.Fields(2).Value = num1 + num2
  rs.MoveNext

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see any reason to use ADO to do this.  Also, your 2 `Set` statements are unnecessary since you've already initialized the variables in your `Dim` statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a calculate option then: `Range.Calculate` is what you need... but a much simpler way of doing this  (Assuming you are doing col A + col B = col C?):

```
Dim LastRow As Long, CurRow As Long

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For CurRow = 2 to LastRow '(assumes col header in row 1)
    Cells(CurRow, 3).Formula = "=A" & CurRow & "+B" & CurRow
Next CurRow
```

Comment: Ya calculation is same.But I need to achieve it using ADO RecordSet.That is the requirement @ Chrismas007

Comment: Have you tried clearing the variables `num1` and `num2`?  Are you saying in your problem that the values (sum) from the first row is being applied to all "3rd col" values instead of going row by row?

Comment: "In ADO 2.5 and later, when the Recordset has been filtered or sorted and the data of the current record is changed, calling the MoveNext method moves the cursor two records forward from the current record. This is because when the current record is changed, the next record becomes the new current record. Calling MoveNext after the change moves the cursor one record forward from the new current record."